# Прошу помочь! Задача на acmp, как решить ее?638

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

[Задача acmp 0638](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=638)

### Всероссийская олимпиада по информатике

*(Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 37%)*

2127 год. Прошло уже много лет с тех пор, как состоялась первая Всероссийская олимпиада по информатике. Как и многие другие соревнования, наши олимпиады теперь проводятся в несколько дней. Теперь даже задача выбора подходящего времени для олимпиады представляет определенные трудности. Ведь на разных планетах, входящих в состав Российской Федерации используются разные способы отсчета времени: длина месяца, количество дней в неделе и те дни, по которым невозможно проведение олимпиады, могут различаться. Возникла необходимость написания программы, которая поможет решить эту задачу. И тогда в жюри вспомнят, что уже сейчас мы предвидели такую ситуацию и предложили вам решить подобную задачу.

В качестве первого шага найдите количество способов выбрать время проведения олимпиады.

### Входные данные

В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT содержатся два целых числа n и k (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 100000) - количество дней месяца и продолжительность олимпиады соответственно. Во второй строке задаются количество дней в неделе w, количество дней, запрещенных еженедельно, dw и день недели, на который приходится первый день месяца s (1 ≤ s ≤ w ≤ n, 0 ≤ dw ≤ w). Третья строка содержит dw номеров дней недели (например, выходных), в которые нельзя проводить олимпиаду. В четвертой строке записано количество дней месяца dm, не подходящих для проведения олимпиады по причинам отличным от еженедельного распорядка (например, такими днями являются государственные праздники). Последняя строка содержит dm целых чисел - номера этих дней. Дни месяца так же нумеруются начиная с 1. Заметим, что некоторые дни могут быть запрещенными сразу по обеим причинам.

### Выходные данные

В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите единственное целое число - количество способов выбрать k подряд идущих дней, в которые возможно проведение олимпиады.

вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
 long long n,k,g,count,sum = 0;
 cin >> n >> k;
 vector <vector <long long>> dp(n + 1,vector<long long> (2, 0));
 long long w, nt, s, ch = 1, unid;
 cin >> w >> nt >> s;
 count = s;
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
   dp[i][1] = count;
   if(count == w)
   {count = 0;}
   count++;
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < nt; i++)
 {
  cin >> unid;
  for(int z = 0; z < n; z += ch)
  {
    if(dp[z][1] == unid)
    {
      dp[z][0] = -1;
      ch = w;
    }
  }
 }
 ch = 1;
 cin >> g;
 for(int i = 0; i < g; i++)
 {
  cin >> unid;
  dp[unid - 1][0] = -1;
 }
 int last = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
   if(i + k > n){break;}
   if(dp[i][0] == -1){continue;}
   if(dp[i + k - 1][0] == -1){ i = i + k - 1;continue;}
   dp[i][0] = dp[i][0] + last + 1;
   last = dp[i][0];
 }
 int res = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
 if(res < dp[i][0]){res = dp[i][0];}
 }
 cout << res << endl;
}
```

Comment: В чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что курил автор задачи о "планетах, входящих в состав РФ" :)

Comment: @Harry, вы последний век что ли в берлоге сидели? :) http://ttolk.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/s_gorzus_rossiej_var_2.jpg

Comment: @Zhihar Похоже, никак не менее 540 лет :) Подумать только — 540 лет, и все еще никак победить не могут, все воюют... :(

Answer (score 1):

Да все просто...
Решаем "в лоб".

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k,n,w,dw,s;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> v(n+1,1);
    cin >> w >> dw >> s;
    for(int j = 0; j < dw; ++j)
    {
        int d; cin >> d; int i = d - s + 1;
        while(i < 1) i += w;
        while(i > w) i -= w;
        for(; i <= n; i += w) v[i] = 0;
    }
    cin >> dw;
    for(int j = 0; j < dw; ++j)
    {
        int d; cin >> d;
        v[d] = 0;
    }
    int cnt = 0;
    w = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (v[i]) {
            ++w;
            if (w >= k) cnt++;
        }
        else w = 0;
    }
    cout << cnt;
}
```

Comment: По времени проходит наверняка. Изящнее смотрелось бы решение за время пропорциональное объёму входа (не длине месяца). Распишите как работает последний цикл, пожалуйста.

Comment: Последний цикл - просто смотрим длину непрерывного участка разрешенных дней, и если k и более - считаем варианты...